# Apple Scripting Error

Tags: applescript

I want to search for an installed app in the Application folder, with the below code am not able to do the same, pls suggest me the correct way.

```
tell application "Finder"

    if folder "Applications" of startup disk contains "Safari" then
        return true
    else
        return false
    end if
end tell
```

I got the code to chk for existing app, if the app is not present When that's the case, AppleScript pops up a dialog titled "Choose Application" that asks, "Where is AppYouDontHave?", Pls correct the same.

modified code

```
tell application "Finder"
    if application "Safari" exists then
        tell application "Safari"
            set safariVersion to version
            return version
        end tell
    else
        false
    end if
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the id

```
get id of application "Safari"
```

returns "com.apple.Safari"

```
  try
        exists application id "com.apple.Safari"
    on error
        return false
    end try
```

This should address your modified comments:

```
try
    tell application "Finder" to set theApp to get first item of folder "Applications" of the startup disk whose name is "Safari.app"
on error
    return false
end try
version of theApp
```

Comment: it works for the app installed in Mac, if the app is not present how do i get the app id??, here also Applescript opens a dialog popup as mentioned in the modified comments.